# How to switch off non-java logs in an Openshift container?

Tags: java, security, encryption, passwords, openshift

I have a Spring Boot application which is deployed to Openshift.
When starting, container logs some sensitive data passed to application (passwords, accounts):

```
Starting the java application using /opt/jboss/container/java/run/java-run.sh...
INFO exec java -Dpassword=uncrypted_value...
```

How to switch these logs off but leave other logs from Java app "as is"?
base64-ing passwords already applied in Openshift secrets

Comment: You figure this out, I don't have an answer but might be nice to know!